# Android debug error: "Execution failed for task" and "Manifest merger failed"

Tags: android

I import an project into Android Studio and debug it. Then it shows this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1

Comment: you are using API 20 and you have selected minsdkversion 8 so that's why it is not working change version API level to 19

Answer (score 1):

You are using the incorrect version of API by the sounds of it. Try changing it down (as i was writing this, @Darkie commented, saying '19') which should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the build.gradle file probably has com.android.suport:support-v4+ or something similar. This is basically telling the build to include whatever the latest support library is, so in this case it is using the release candidate which is for android L.

Change your build.gradle so that it is `com.android.support:support-v4:20` and re-sync your gradle files and rebuild, your problem should be fixed then.